# Unable to connect to MongoDB via Compass or VScode

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Im running my webapp in docker containers. The following is part of my docker compose file.

```yaml
  # some frontend container...

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./backend/:/code/
  db:
    container_name: mongo-db
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/data/db
volumes:
  mongodata:
    driver: local
```

Outside the container I try to connect my MongoDB compass to `27017` or even use VSCode to connect to `27017`, however the DB they connect to look different from the DB in my container.

Are there 2 different active instances of MongoDB at the same port `27017` and I'm only able to see the one outside the container even tho I mapped my ports? Any advice on debugging this?

I connect my backend to the db at `'mongodb://mongo-db:27017/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try To connect to your MongoDB instance with specified database name, use the following connection string from outside the container

```
'mongodb://localhost:27017/my-db'
```

and this from inside the container

```
'mongodb://mongo-db:27017/my-db'
```

add this to docker-compose

```
environment:
  - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=my-db
```

If this configuration does not work, you can change the exposed port:

```
ports:
  - 27018:27017
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out! turns out the mongodb server on my host computer was, unbeknownst to me, running in the background at '27017' and somehow i guess this overwrote or had more priority than my container mapped port. I change the ports to '27018' - as you said, and now it works fine! Thanks!